# checking validity for standard SOAP web service

Tags: visual-studio-2010, web-services, wsdl, asmx

Is this a valid web service link since I tried ti import it several times to visual studio 2010 and 2012 and couldnt read it from code behind.

http://www.hotelston.com/ws/HotelService?wsdl

whats the service name I should call ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is a valid WSDL and it is a WSI compliant WSDL as well. I ran the tests with SOAP UI and it appears to be fine. The service name is `HotelService` it has three ports one for `SOAP 1.1` another for `SOAP 1.2` and finally one for `HTTP`. It is document literal wrapped so cant see anything problematic.

I also imported the WSDL into a XML editor and had a look. It appears fine see image below.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, But when I import this web service inside my project (visual studio 2010) I cant read the service name (HotelService)